# Hibernate error appearing randomly

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm getting 4 different errors which **randomly** comes while accessing db through hibernate. They are not appearing always, specifically in debug mode. Please tell me various methods to be tried to fix them. Errors are given below.

Ask me if any more information needed.

Error 1:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:85)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Statement!!!
com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:85)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:85)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:78)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1808)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:85)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Error 2:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5727)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5577)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5617)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getString(NewProxyResultSet.java:3342)
org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(StringType.java:41)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2124)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1404)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1332)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1230)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:603)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:83)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Error 3:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:795)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1106)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getLong(ResultSetImpl.java:3022)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getLong(NewProxyResultSet.java:2625)
org.hibernate.type.LongType.get(LongType.java:51)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:1121)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:588)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Error 4:

```
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:222)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerExceptioncom.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.prepareStatement(NewProxyConnection.java:186)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you are closing the sessions after each hibernate transaction. I had a similar problem and was getting 'randomly' the exception org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query. At one place i was not closing the session so I was reaching the limit of the open transactions in my database. I just added sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().close(); and this resolved my issue.
It will be helpful if you can provide some of your code of your dao implementation!

Comment: Its fixed long back. Yes the session was not closing every time. I'm out of that project 6 months ago, so I can't get its code anymore. Anyway I have accepted your answer and upvoted. Please upvote the question too if u think its a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be caused by NullPointerException in `NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl` lines 81/83/85.
Check stack trace to find references to domain classes (non framework).

Sample:

```
com.metropro.eps.dao.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.java:81)
com.metropro.eps.bo.impl.NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.getSeriesDevices(NewlyAddedDevicesBoImpl.java:49)
com.metropro.eps.controller.RepositoryController.getSeriesDevices(RepositoryController.java:105)
```

Add log statements at the begging of `NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices()` to check the values in you DTO to make sure no null values are being used.
Better to add log statements in Controller/BoImpl as well, to check how values in DTO is populated/changed at each layer.

Make sure null values are not dereferenced in `NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices()`.

If possible post code of `NewlyAddedDevicesDaoImpl.getSeriesDevices()`.